# Griffon SwingPad: cannot add label (groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: javax.swing.JLabel.call()..)

Tags: groovy, griffon

I'm quite new to groovy/griffon and playing around with the SwingPad application.

It seems to work fine, but I can't add labels. I've tried button, scrollPane, textArea, panel, all these work fine but adding a label always produces the following exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: javax.swing.JLabel.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[text:label text, constraints:North]]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), add(java.awt.PopupMenu), add(java.awt.Component), each(groovy.lang.Closure)
```

I'm using the latest griffon version 0.9.5 on a Mac. Here is the a very simple script, which doesn't work:

```
panel(id:'main') {
    label(text:'label text')
}
```

The list of installed plugins (from the about dialog of the SwingPad application):

```
coverflow
crystalicons
designgridlayout
effects
glazedlists
i18n-support
jexplose
jxlayer
miglayout
riverlayout
silkicons
swing
syntaxtext
transitions
tray-builder
zonelayout
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the SwingPad shipped with 0.9.5 requires some plugins to be updated before you attempt running it.

Please call `griffon list-plugin-updates --install` and give it another try afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, but now the SwingPad doesn't even start anymore. I'll try a fresh re-install of griffon, maybe the update from 0.9.5-rc to 0.9.5 did not work properly.  BTW: I'm using groovy 1.8.5, should I upgrade to 1.8.6 (I cant find any info at http://griffon.codehaus.org/Installing+Griffon about the required groovy version).

Comment: Griffon uses its own Groovy version (1.8.6) which means you don't need an external one. And even if you have an additional groovy distro installed it won't be touched by Griffon.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
panel(id:'main') {
    label('label text')
}
```

I believe that should work...

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work as well (same exception). IMHO this looks like bug. Does anybody else have the same problem? If so, I would file a bug....

Comment: @DieterRehbein Back at a computer now, running the 0.9.5 SwingPad app, and I'll give it a go

Comment: @DieterRehbein Works for me... :-/ Do you get any exceptions from `griffon run-app` when the application is starting?  Maybe try `griffon clean` first?

Comment: Hm, after a `griffon list-plugin-updates --install` and `griffon clean` the SwingPad doesn't start anymore (due to an NPE while building griffon.samples.swingpad.SwingPadMenuBar). Seams to be a problem with my dev-environment. I will try a fresh re-install of griffon, maybe the update from 0.9.5-rc2 to 0.9.5 did not work properly....

Comment: @DieterRehbein Yeah, I hit that as well...  Comment out the body of the `makeSampleScriptAction` inside that class and it should all work again